# For all sets A,B ,C , if A∩B = ∅, then ( A×C ) ∩ (B × C) = ∅.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

More info:
For each statement below, determine whether the statement is true or false. Justify your answers. All sets are contained in a universal set U.

For all sets A,B ,C , if  A∩B  = ∅, then ( A×C ) ∩ (B × C) = ∅.

I'm not really 100% sure on how to begin this problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I know it may have to do with proof by contradiction or something similar, but I am not sure on how to handle the cross product portion of the question.

Comment: Notice that $(A \times C) \cap (B \times C) \neq \emptyset$ would imply that there exists at least one element $(x, y)$ in both $(A \times C)$ and $B \times C$.  Considering this, what must be true about $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y)\in( A×C ) ∩ (B × C)\ne ∅$

Then $(x,y)\in A\times C$ and $(x,y)\in B\times C$

Then $x\in A $ and $y\in B$

Then $A ∩ B \ne \phi$

Comment: Typo: $x \in A, x \in B, y \in C$